# rails multiple STI relation has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sti

I have theses models

```rb
class OfferWrapper < ApplicationRecord

end

class PurchaseOfferWrapper < OfferWrapper
  has_many :purchase_offers, dependent: :destroy
end

class Offer < ApplicationRecord
end

class PurchaseOffer < Offer
  belongs_to :purchase_offer_wrapper, foreign_key: :offer_wrapper_id, inverse_of: :purchase_offer
end
```

My migration

```
def change
  create_table :offer_wrappers do |t|
    t.string :ref
    t.timestamp
  end
  add_reference :offers, :offer_wrapper
end
```

but when I try to access to a purchase_offer from a purchase_offer_wrapper i have a foreign_ky error like this

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column offers.purchase_offer_wrapper_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...s" WHERE "offers"."type" IN ('PurchaseOffer') AND "offers"."...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "offers" WHERE "offers"."type" IN ('PurchaseOffer') AND "offers"."purchase_offer_wrapper_id" = $1
```

```
[4] pry(main)> PurchaseOfferWrapper.last.purchase_offers.to_sql
  PurchaseOfferWrapper Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "offer_wrappers".* FROM "offer_wrappers" WHERE "offer_wrappers"."type" IN ('PurchaseOfferWrapper') ORDER BY "offer_wrappers"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> "SELECT \"offers\".* FROM \"offers\" WHERE \"offers\".\"type\" IN ('PurchaseOffer') AND \"offers\".\"purchase_offer_wrapper_id\" = 4806"
```

I use foreign_key option in my `belongs_to` to force `offer_wrapper_id` , but it dosen't work. it still try to use `purchase_offer_wrapper_id`.

Where is my mistake ?

Thanks in avdance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finaly I found the problem.

I have to add `foreign_key` option in my `has_many` association too.

```
class PurchaseOfferWrapper < OfferWrapper
  has_many :purchase_offers, foreign_key: :offer_wrapper_id, dependent: :destroy
end
```